# integrate Drupal with Akamai

Tags: drupal

What is the best way to integrate Drupal with Akamai

With ability to upload files to Akamai servers.

Comment: Does CDN module will work for akamai

Answer (score 1):

[Rackspace Cloud Files](http://www.rackspacecloud.com/1344.html) uses Akamai, and the [cloud_files](http://drupal.org/project/cloud_files) module will put files uploaded to Drupal onto Rackspace Cloud Files, and serve them from the CDN.

Answer (score 1):

The [CDN Module](http://drupal.org/project/cdn) supports pulling or pushing files to a CDN. This allows users to download these assets from the CDN rather then your web server.

The [Akamai module](http://drupal.org/project/akamai) does **not do** this, but is to manage cached versions of pages (HTML) stored in Akamai. This is used to purge pages when pages are updated.

Answer (score 0):

There exists an [Akamai module](http://drupal.org/project/akamai) for both  Drupal 6 and 7.
Otherwise, there is also a [CDN module](http://drupal.org/project/cdn) for 6, however I'm not sure if this one would work with Akamai.

Answer (score 0):

[CDN Module](http://drupal.org/project/cdn) does support Akamai